# How change format to date but whitout times only ddmmyy not ddmmyy hhmmss

Tags: .net, vb.net

hi im try to change the format of my datatable but in one column of format date is give to me format datetime with hours minutes and seconds like that '"08/11/2021 0:00:00"' im want only the date not the time .

```
try 
    Dim valor as DateTime = datatable.Rows(i)(j)
    Dim value1 As String = dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(1) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(0) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(2)
    Dim value2 As String = Format(value1, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    Dim value3 As String = CDate(dataTable.Rows(i)(j)).ToString("dd/MM/yyy")
```

excel original format of date

[image]

[image]

The code that I added is a part of a try accompanied by a while that basically as long as there are columns with data in my datatable (datatable.dataset) it will go through I & j and I have a selectvalue since, according to the type of export, other changes will be applied to it. It is only necessary to generate the split file, now as my datatable as I am reading the excel file it is with the following routine

```
   If extension.Equals(".xls") Then
                    Wbook = ExcelWorkbook.ReadXLS(sArchivo)
                End If
                If extension.Equals(".xlsx") Then
                    Wbook = ExcelWorkbook.ReadXLSX(sArchivo)
                End If
                Dim reader As IExcelDataReader
                Dim stream = File.Open(sArchivo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
                Dim conf = New ExcelDataSetConfiguration With {
        .ConfigureDataTable = Function(__) New ExcelDataTableConfiguration With {
            .UseHeaderRow = True
        }
    }

                Dim dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf)
```

later I close the reader so that it does not generate errors of open excel files I free up the memory space of the dataset and I remove the assignment to the reader

```
Dim dataTable = dataSet.Tables(0)

                reader.Close()
                reader.Dispose()
                reader = Nothing
```

After closing the datareader and having my datatable with the excel data that you want to export, the aforementioned do while begins, depending on the very simple select value, it will perform that row and column traversal.
It is there where the 2-column format changes and the time hour minutes and seconds is added to it and I have tried to extract the date with Cdate and then with tostring assign the format but it has not resulted in the conversions, I really don't understand why it was changed the date to datetime format at first I thought it was because of the datareader but it shouldn't affect the file as such.

```
Do While (j < columnCount)
                            Try
                                If (dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString() <> DBNull.Value.ToString()) Then
                                    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString) Then
                                        allNull = False

                                    End If
                                    If ddlTipoAccion.SelectedValue = 1 Then 'Alta Titular y Carga
                                        If (j = 2) Or (j = 3) Or (j = 11) Then
                                            Try
                                                Dim valor As DateTime = dataTable.Rows(i)(j)
                                                Dim value1 As String = dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(1) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(0) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(2)
                                                Dim value2 As String = Format(value1, "dd/MM/yyyy")
                                                Dim value3 As String = CDate(dataTable.Rows(i)(j)).ToString("dd/MM/yyy")




                                                'dataTable.Rows(i)(j) = dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(1) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(0) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(2)



                                                'dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))

                                                'Debug.Print(Convert.ToDateTime(dataTable.Rows(2)("vdesde")).ToShortDateString)








                                            Catch ex As Exception
                                                Dim er As String = ex.Message
                                            End Try
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                    If ddlTipoAccion.SelectedValue = 3 Then 'Baja Titular
                                        If (j = 4) Then
                                            Try
                                                dataTable.Rows(i)(j) = dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(1) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(0) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(2)
                                            Catch ex As Exception

                                            End Try
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                    If ddlTipoAccion.SelectedValue = 4 Then 'Baja Carga
                                        If (j = 6) Then
                                            Try
                                                dataTable.Rows(i)(j) = dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(1) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(0) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(2)
                                            Catch ex As Exception

                                            End Try
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                    If ddlTipoAccion.SelectedValue = 767 Then 'Traspasos -> estaba el 7 en este punto pero lo dejo con dato(767) segun la ultima fuente entregada
                                        If (j = 6) Then
                                            Try
                                                dataTable.Rows(i)(j) = dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(1) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(0) + "-" + dataTable.Rows(i)(j).ToString().Split("/")(2)
                                            Catch ex As Exception

                                            End Try
                                        End If
                                    End If

                                End If

                            Catch ex As Exception
                                'SiAuto.Main.LogColored(Level.Error, System.Drawing.Color.Red, ex.Message)
                            End Try

                            j = (j + 1)
                        Loop

                        If allNull Then
                            dataTable.Rows(i).Delete()
                        End If

                        i = (i - 1)
                    Loop
```

sorry my english help me with the translate

Comment: I would of thought using either  the String.Format or ToString methodes you've mentioned above would work.  Theirs is also the DateTime.ToShortDateString method that might work.  If not maybe update your question with complete code that compiles and a clear explanation of why each method doesn't suit

Comment: What's the datatype of that column and what kind of database are you using?

Comment: the db is oracle and yes  and I will explain the post in more detail for more context

Answer (score 0):

.NET `DateTime` values are simply numbers under the hood. They have no format. Format is only an issue when you create a `String` representation of a `DateTime` value. It looks like you are displaying your data in a `DataGridView`, so the grid is creating the text. If you want the text to only contain the date then you have to tell the grid that. You do that by setting the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property of the appropriate column. That property will accept the same format specifiers as the `DateTime.ToString` method. That means that, if you want to use the system short date format, you should set the property to `"d"`. If you want a specific format then you should use the appropriate custom format specifier, e.g. `"dd/MM/yyyy"`. Note that is is generally better to use the system formats, so that every use sees what they expect to see.